# Is my guppy pregnant!? I hope so!

Tags: fish, pregnancy

is my guppy pregnant? I'm not sure:
[image]
[image]

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Out-if-Your-Guppy-Is-Pregnant

Comment: I would say yes!